# I defer a function return function, what is the order

Tags: go

I write the follow code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() func() {
        fmt.Println("start")
        return func() {
            fmt.Println("end")
        }

    }()()
    fmt.Println("aaaa")
    return

}
```

and I except output is aaaa start end

but actual output is start aaaa end

I can't understand why output "start" before "aaaa"

Comment: You are calling the `func() func()` which is called and returns the `func()` which `defer` is calling. See the double parens at the end `}()()`. You are calling the first, `defer` is told to call the second one returned from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked.

The deferred function call is the last `()` in the defer statement. The expression returning the function value is evaluated at the time of the defer statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since defer statement needs to evaluate the statement, in your code, the func() (the func() right after "defer"  keyword) returns a function type, defer statement needs to actually execute the func() to get the return function. So your code prints out "start" first.

If your function does not return a function type, then the function body will not be executed until enclosing function returns.